# AAC Decoder Android Media Codec (Data from Gstreamer)

Tags: android, gstreamer, android-mediacodec, aac, mediaextractor

I want to Stream Audio from my Raspberry with G-Streamer to my Android phone. In Gstreamer I use the following pipeline:
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! faac ! "audio/mpeg, mpegversion=4" ! mux. mpegtsmux name=mux ! udpsink host=224.0.0.1 port=8001

faac endcodes the Audio to AAC LC (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-plugins/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-faac.html)

and mpegtsmux creates a MPEG-TS stream (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-plugins/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-mpegtsmux.html)

I tried to make the Android App with Android Studio by myself.
I'm receiving the Data with a Multicastsocket. Then I tried to implement an AAC decoder with media codec and media extractor. The extractor.setDataSource methode doesn't work directly with sockets, so I write the data to a file and let the extractor get its Data from the File and pass it to the MediaCodec to create the Decoder.

The extractor seems to realize that its AAC but something is wrong with the decoder I think. This is the important part of the code:

```
MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);

    extractor.setDataSource(path.toString());

format = extractor.getTrackFormat(0); 
        String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME); 
        decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime); 
        decoder.configure(format, null, null, 0); 


        while (!stopTrack) { 


            multicastSocket.receive(packet); 

            decoder.start(); 
            data = packet.getData(); 

            inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers(); 
            outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers(); 
            inputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(-1); 

            if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) 
            { 
                inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex]; 
                inputBuffer.clear(); 

                inputBuffer.put(data); 

                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, data.length, 0, 0); 
            } 

            bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo(); 
            outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0); 

            while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) 
            { 
                outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex]; 

                outputBuffer.position(bufferInfo.offset); 
                outputBuffer.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size); 

                outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size]; 
                outputBuffer.get(outData); 

                //  Log.d("AudioDecoder", outData.length + " bytes decoded"); 

               track.write(outData, 0, outData.length); 

                decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false); 
                outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0); 

            }
```

These are all the messages I receive in the logcat:

```
D/ExtendedUtils: Try creating ExtendedExtractor 
E/MM_OSAL: FileSource::FileSource 
E/MM_OSAL: FileSource::FileSource m_bEveryThingOK 1 
E/MM_OSAL: MM_File_Create File Name /data/mmosal_logmask.cfg , Mode 0 
E/MM_OSAL: MM_File_Create failed .Efs Error No -1 , File Name      /data/mmosal_logmask.cfg , Mode 0 
E/MM_OSAL: Open or read fail on /data/mmosal_logmask.cfg. Possible permission denied issue. Looking for /data/misc/media/mmosal_logmask.cfg 
E/MM_OSAL: MM_File_Create File Name /data/misc/media/mmosal_logmask.cfg , Mode 0  
E/MM_OSAL: MM_File_Create failed .Efs Error No -1 , File Name /data/misc/media/mmosal_logmask.cfg , Mode 0 
E/MMParserExtractor:  FileSourceWrapper::New returned NULL 
D/ExtendedUtils: default extractor is NULL, return extended extractor 
E/MM_OSAL: FileSource::FileSource 
E/MM_OSAL: FileSource::FileSource m_bEveryThingOK 1 
E/MM_OSAL: MM_File_Create File Name /data/mmosal_logmask.cfg , Mode 0 
E/MM_OSAL: MM_File_Create failed .Efs Error No -1 , File Name /data/mmosal_logmask.cfg , Mode 0 
E/MM_OSAL: Open or read fail on /data/mmosal_logmask.cfg. Possible permission denied issue. Looking for /data/misc/media/mmosal_logmask.cfg 
E/MM_OSAL: MM_File_Create File Name /data/misc/media/mmosal_logmask.cfg , Mode 0 
E/MM_OSAL: MM_File_Create failed .Efs Error No -1 , File Name /data/misc/media/mmosal_logmask.cfg , Mode 0 
E/MM_OSAL: parseTransportStreamPacket isPESPacket failed 18954 
E/MM_OSAL: parseTransportStreamPacket isPESPacket failed 18783 
E/MM_OSAL: parseTransportStreamPacket isPESPacket failed 18954 
E/MM_OSAL: parseTransportStreamPacket isPESPacket failed 18783 
I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux. 
E/OMXMaster: A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one. 
D/MediaCodec: MediaCodec[kWhatConfigure]: video-output-protection: 00000000, audio-output-protection: 00000000 
E/Format:: audio/mp4a-latm 
W/SoftAAC2: aacDecoder_DecodeFrame decoderErr = 0x4004 
W/SoftAAC2: AAC decoder returned error 0x4004, substituting silence 
I/SoftAAC2: Reconfiguring decoder: 0->44100 Hz, 0->0 channels
```

As I said I wrote some of the audio data to a file where the extractor gets its informations from. This file is playable! Even with the normal Android Music app. So I thing the part of receiving the data works well. 
Something must be wrong with extractor or decoder, probably decoder because extractor realises the format is AAC. I also downloaded an AAC test file, but same problem and fail messages.

I hope someone can help me! Thanks for any help!